# The user privileges I have assigned don't work when someone imports my .sql database file on mySQL

Tags: mysql, backup, permissions, mysqldump

I'm new to SQLs and mySQL, I and my colleagues who are also new to SQLs are working on a database project and I have successfully queried its structures and inserted data into them.

I then created users and passwords for each of the team members through the commands

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and then I have checked that it's all been queried successfully for each one of them through

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost';
```

I then proceeded to backup my database .sql file through

```
mysqldump -u root -p databasename > databasenameBackup.sql
```

I have sent them the databasenameBackup.sql file, and when they import it on their machines, it works and they get my database with its structures and data.

The issue is that they can start querying, deleting, inserting, creating tables, dropping, deleting etc. immediately after they successfully import the .sql file without even needing to enter the usernames and passwords that I have provided to them.

How can I force them to enter the user credentials that I have assigned to them before they start editing the database?

Comment: If your colleagues are using a MySQL installation on their own system, and they have `root` access to their database, there is nothing you can do beyond asking nicely. The user accounts on your server are not part of the data dump.

Comment: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` isn't required on `CREATE USER` or `GRANT`.